# Sort kay-value based on key in descending order

Tags: php

Say i have an array like,

```
$x = [1012 => "banana",2012 => "orange", 2 => "chocolate"];
```

I should be getting the result like:

```
$x = [2012 => "orange",1012 => "banana",2 => "chocolate"];
```

So in the descending order based on the number in the key positions.

Comment: [`krsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php).  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`krsort()`](http://www.php.net/krsort) for this

```
$x = [1012 => "banana",2012 => "orange", 2 => "chocolate"];
krsort($x);
```

Comment: You're welcome. The [comparison of array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) is worth a look as well